# Order By is ignored in Rails Group By query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

All I'm trying to do is order posts by the number of impressions (an impression is created when someone views the post) over the past 7 days. This is my named scope

```
scope :popular_last_week, unscoped
    .select("websites.*, COUNT(impressions.id) AS counted_impressions")
    .joins("INNER JOIN impressions ON websites.id = impressions.impressionable_id")
    .where("impressions.created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)
    .where(:is_published => true)
    .group("websites.id")
    .order("counted_impressions DESC")
```

("counted_impressions" is used to avoid a conflict on post record)

Yet this produces the following invalid SQL (counted_impressions is not a valid column):

`SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, websites.id AS websites_id FROM "websites" INNER JOIN impressions ON websites.id = impressions.impressionable_id WHERE "websites"."is_published" = 't' AND (impressions.created_at >= '2013-01-11 17:48:03.954542') GROUP BY websites.id ORDER BY counted_impressions`

Seems the select statement is just ignored. Where am I going wrong, or how should I do it so that the SQL statement is:

`SELECT  websites.*, COUNT(impressions.id) AS counted_impressions FROM "websites" INNER JOIN impressions ON websites.id = impressions.impressionable_id 
WHERE "websites"."is_published" = 't' AND (impressions.created_at >= '2013-01-11 17:42:57.771777') GROUP BY websites.id ORDER BY counted_impressions DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  scope :popular_last_week, unscoped
    .select(arel_table[Arel.star])
    .select(Website.arel_table[:id].count.as("counted_impressions"))
    .joins("INNER JOIN impressions ON websites.id = impressions.impressionable_id")
    .where("impressions.created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)
    .where(:is_published => true)
    .group("websites.id")
    .order("counted_impressions DESC")
```

Comment: Ah sadly not: "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: counted_impressions" - SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, websites.id AS websites_id FROM "websites" INNER JOIN impressions ON websites.id = impressions.impressionable_id WHERE "websites"."is_published" = 't' AND (impressions.created_at >= '2013-01-12 00:48:58.614179') GROUP BY websites.id ORDER BY counted_impressions

Comment: Could you add a small schema, so I can try to recreate the scope with the relevant models.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the query should be:

```
SELECT count(*) AS impression_count, w.id AS website_id 
FROM websites as w
INNER JOIN impressions as i ON w.id = i.impressionable_id 
WHERE w.is_published = 't' AND i.created_at >= '2013-01-11 17:48:03.954542'
GROUP BY w.id 
ORDER BY impression_count DESC;
```

Seems like you could skip the join in this query and then run the "is_published" check on the next query to get the actual post data... assuming you're only using this query to get a list of ID's for a second query that gets the data.